# It is possible to create a web tool on jira?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I want to create a web based tool , that will create a document formed from a list of (Jira) tickets selected by users , it is possible to make this thing in Jira, so I should not have to handle the authentication , or I have to make it separated ?

Comment: What you are saying is similar to Atlassian Confluence or I'm confused?

Comment: No , I want to make a web page inside of Jira that will make some jobs for users , So in this way I should not take care of users  authentication.

Comment: Frankly speaking I doubt that such a thing exist even by a third party add-ons cause people use Confluence for documentations. If you have a concern about authentication, you can have JIRA as an External User Directory in Confluence :-)